# Outlook won't recognize ssl certificate (iredMail mail server)

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, outlook, iredmail

I have installed iRedMail on a server and have set it up with a bought SSL certificate from Comodo/ Sectigo. When I connect my users to the mail server with Outlook I get "The server you are connected to is using a security certificate that cannot be verified. The target principal is incorrect.". On the view Certificate button I see my valid SSL certificate, but on every operation in Outlook I get the same message. I have added the certificate as trusted, but that changes nothing. Can I disable this prompt, or what can the problem be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The hostnames must match**

The hostnames for incoming and outgoing mail server on the *Server Information* provided in the *POP and IMAP Account Settings* must match the hostname in the sertificate. If the certificate is for e.g. `mail.example.com`, you should use exactly that hostname instead of e.g. `imap.example.com` and `smtp.example.com`, despite they probably have the same `A` record (or `CNAME` to it) in DNS.

For the current versions of Outlook you can only access these settings through the Control Panel item "Mail (Microsoft Outlook)", *Email Account...*

**The certificate chain must be complete**

For the Comodo/Sectigo certificates you might need to make the server send the whole certificate chain up to the trusted root certificate. Please refer to the following documentations:

- Sectigo: [How to Download & Install Sectigo Intermediate Certificates - RSA](https://support.sectigo.com/articles/Knowledge/Sectigo-Intermediate-Certificates)
- iRedMail: [Use a bought SSL certificate](https://docs.iredmail.org/use.a.bought.ssl.certificate.html), namely section [Replace cert files](https://docs.iredmail.org/use.a.bought.ssl.certificate.html#replace-cert-files). The `iRedMail.crt` (or `combined.pem` with iRedMail easy platform) must include the full chain, referred as `fullchain.pem`.